# vuejs filter function shows an empty array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I create a filter function and I want to show the result. Here's the code

```
    data() {
        return {
            questionList: faqData.flatMap(q => q.questions)
        }
    },
    computed: {
        search() {
            return this.$store.state.search
        },
        filter: function() {
            this.questionList.filter((x) => {
                return x.question.match(this.search);
            })
        }
    }
```

There's no problem with the `questionList` variable and the `search()` function. And I think the problem is in the `filter()` function. Anyway, here's my questionList

```
[{id: 1, question: 'blabla', answer: 'blabalbla'}, {id: 2, question: 'blabla', answer: 'blabalbla'}, {id: 3, question: 'blabla', answer: 'blabalbla'} ]
```

the filter function shows an empty array. Can anyone tell me where did I do it wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to save the computed function to a variable anyway? `this.result` and `this.filter` are completely the same.

Answer (score 1):

Computed properties' values are defined by what their functions return.

In your case `undefined` since `filter: function() {` does not return anything.

**It is not a good idea at all to assign a state variable inside a computed property function!**

The correct way to do it is:

```
    filter: function() {
        return this.questionList.filter((question) => {
            return question.title.match(this.search);
        })
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your explanation! I actually wrote that code previously, without saving in a variable called result. But the problem is I want to loop the result of this filter function, like this `v-for="x in filter"` but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: How doesn't it work? Can you link to a reproduction?

Answer (score 0):

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">   
    <div>
      <p v-for="(item, index) in filt" :key="index">
        {{item.question}}
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      questionList: faqData.flatMap(q => q.questions)
    }
  },
  computed: {
        search() {
            return this.$store.state.search;
        },
        filt: function() {
            return this.questionList.filter((x) => {
                return x.question.match(this.search);
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```